# How to plot x axis next to 0th y axis tick label in case of negative data?

Tags: highcharts

I want to plot x axis next to 0th y axis tick label in case of negative data. Refer Image: [To plot Xaxis next to 0th tick label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zouIf.png)
Is there any way to achieve this in Highcharts?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this **live working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/gxxtfn67/

I slightly modified the code of **xAxis zero crossing plugin** (https://github.com/ppoliani/xAxis-zero-crossing). I enabled rendering of the y axis and removed the line responsible for positioning x axis labels. The final code looks like this:

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'render', function (proceed) {

        var chart = this.chart,
            xAxis, yAxis, extremes, crossing;

        if (typeof this.options.zeroCrossing === 'boolean') {
            xAxis = chart['xAxis'][0];
            yAxis = chart['yAxis'][0];
            extremes = yAxis.getExtremes();
            crossing = Math.abs(extremes.min) + Math.abs(extremes.max);
            this.offset = yAxis.toPixels(crossing, true);
            chart.axisOffset[this.side] = 10;

        }
        proceed.call(this);

    });

}(Highcharts));
```

---

**UPDATE**

Live working demo for **bar** series (inverted chart): http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/gyp8n9ou/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, same solution does not work if chart type is changed to bar : http://jsfiddle.net/gxxtfn67/4

Comment: Thanks for your reply!